# Get other columns after applying unique / distinct on one column of dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, unique

### The Problem

I am trying to get selected columns across a dataframe, however the column against whom I am trying to get the selected columns needs to be unique

### The Scenario

So, the Dataframe has all values in strings, and please don't try to relate anything looking at data. The DF looks something like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Hello | 1 | txt | num |
| 123 | Bello | 2 | txt | doub |
| 7 | nice | 1 | txt | num |
| 54 | duke | 1 | txt | num |
| 9901 | - | 3 | char | doub |
| 63.38 | - | 4 | char | deci |
| 8331 | - | 3 | char | doub |
| 91 | , | 5 | char | num |

and I want to run a `.unique()` on column `C` and get the `D` and `E` Column along with distinct / unique values of `C`.

### The Trial

Now, I have achieved my output as I want but I am sure this can be done in very few lines too. For the record, here's my code. The `main_df` contains the above table.

```
dependent_variables = ["D", "E"]
Dictionary = pd.DataFrame()

new_book = {}
dependent_variables_index = []

for no, col in enumerate(main_df.columns):
    print(no, col)
    if col in dependent_variables:
        dependent_variables_index.append(no)

for cid in total_categories:
    try:
        new_book[cid] = main_df[main_df["C"] == int(cid)].iloc[0, dependent_variables_index].to_dict()
    except KeyError:
        new_book[cid] = main_df[main_df["C"] == str(cid)].iloc[0, dependent_variables_index].to_dict()

for k, v in new_book.items():
    Dictionary = Dictionary.append(v, ignore_index=True)

Dictionary.index = list(new_book.keys())
Category_Dictionary = Dictionary.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "C"})
```

### The Expected Output

| C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | txt | num |
| 2 | txt | doub |
| 3 | char | doub |
| 4 | char | deci |
| 5 | char | num |

Again, I could generate this output, however I am looking for more optimized way to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it:

```
df[['C','D','E']].drop_duplicates('C')
```

Output:

```
   C     D     E
0  1   txt   num
1  2   txt  doub
4  3  char  doub
5  4  char  deci
7  5  char   num
```

Comment: Dayum, it was that easy! You've come 2nd time to my aid @Quang. I think, I need to look more for documentation for data transformation.